# Free online analysis board between two players (both players can move the board)

Tags: analysis

Other than F.I.C.S., where can a friend and I analyse our games online together free where both of us can move the pieces on the board.

Answer (score 7):

**Lichess.org** has a feature called [studies](https://lichess.org/blog/V0KrLSkAAMo3hsi4/study-chess-the-lichess-way). You can add your game as a *chapter* in a study, invite your friends as contributors and make that study public or private. You have a (rather weak) engine analysis, a small database of chess games, and a chat. You can annotate your game, add alternative lines and so on.
The multi-chapter option makes that very useful for much more than game analysis. I'm using it primarily for opening studies.

Here is a screenshot from my [Caro-Kann study](https://lichess.org/study/4Aqycynk):

[image]

Not free, but also worth a mention: **Chess24.com** has an analysis board for premium members. Very similar features, but there is only one game per analysis, not multiple chapters. The database is better (larger and properly cleaned up names, lichess is sometimes a bit annoying in that regard). You have to *start a broadcast* (see screenshot), and then you can invite your friend who doesn't need a premium membership for that. The downside is that the chat vanishes once you stop the broadcast.

[image]

In both cases you can move pieces on the board, and all other participants can see and annotate these moves.

Comment: Why do you say the engine analysis at lichess is weak? Stockfish is afaik one of the strongest engines out there, if not the strongest. Unless the depth is somehow limited very much, I can't imagine the engine strength to be below GM level.

Comment: @TMM The depth is per default 21. That's good enough for simple tactics, but nothing more. If you want to get good moves in complex positions, you need at least depth 40.